# Riccati transformation about fisher-information

Tags: fisher-information

my question is about, how to find the Substitute term f(x)=sqrt(g(x)/g(0)), with  g(0)=1

I(μ) =∫ (g′(x))^2/g(x)) dx. (Fisher-Information)

How did he finde f(x) ?

thanks everyone